# Python/Batch: Use Python to press any key to continue

Tags: python, batch-file, python-3.x, automation

I am using a python script to automate a process involving batch files.  These are batch files that are used for other applications and I am not allowed to edit them.

At the end of the batch file, it prompts the following:

"Press any key to continue ..."

How do I use python to recognize when this prompt appears, and how do I respond to it?  I want to be able to close the file so I can run the next batch file.

Currently I have found the following solution, but it's terrible and makes me feel dirty inside:

```
#Run the batch file with parameter DIABFile
subprocess.Popen([path + '\\' + batchFile, path + '\\' + DIABFile])

#Sit here like an idiot until I'm confident the batch file is finished
time.sleep(4)

#Press any key
virtual_keystrokes.press('enter')
```

Any ideas?

#### Attempt #1

```
p = subprocess.Popen([path + '\\' + batchFile, path + '\\' + DIABFile],
                 bufsize=1, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

while p.poll() is None:
    line = p.stdout.readline()
    print(line)
    if line.startswith('Press any key to continue'):
        p.communicate('\r\n')
```

Resulted in the following output and error:

```
b'\r\n'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\workspace\Perform_QAC_Check\Perform_QAC_Check.py", line 341, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\workspace\Perform_QAC_Check\Perform_QAC_Check.py", line 321, in main
    run_setup_builderenv(sandboxPath, DIABFile)
  File "C:\workspace\Perform_QAC_Check\Perform_QAC_Check.py", line 126, in run_setup_builderenv
    if line.startswith('Press any key to continue'):
TypeError: startswith first arg must be bytes or a tuple of bytes, not str
The process tried to write to a nonexistent pipe.
```

The part that seemed weirdest to me was that the startswith first arg must be bytes or a tuple of bytes, not str.  I looked up the documentation and it definitely should be a string? [tutorial of startswith](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_startswith.htm)

So I looked online and found [this](http://adventuresofacomputerscientist.blogspot.com/2011/12/using-nltk-with-python-3-2_16.html) little bit.

> The error message seems to be a bug in Python, as it is exactly the other way around. But still, no problems here, add after line #75 in indian.py

```
try:
    line = line.decode()
except AttributeError:
    pass
```

And so I did.

#### Attempt #2

```
p = subprocess.Popen([path + '\\' + batchFile, path + '\\' + DIABFile],
                 bufsize=1, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

while p.poll() is None:
    line = p.stdout.readline()
    print(line)
    try:
        line = line.decode()
        if line.startswith('Press any key to continue'):
            p.communicate('\r\n')
    except AttributeError:
        pass
```

Resulted in the following output:

```
b'\r\n'
b'Build Environment is created.\r\n'
b'\r\n'
b'Please Refer to the directory: C:/directory\r\n'
b'\r\n'
```

And then it hangs there... That is the last output before the "Please press any key to continue" should show up, but it never does.

#### Notes

I have since taken the second script and asked it to find "Please Refer", which it does.  Unfortunately, then the script hangs again at the line:

```
p.communicate('\r\n')
```

Ending the program, again, prints the error:

```
The process tried to write to a nonexistent pipe.
```

Which I believe is related to [this](http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/python/python/133156) bug.

I can't imagine what I'm trying to do is THAT out of the ordinary.  Since this is seemingly a little more complicated than expected I would like to say I am using XP and Python version 3.3.

Comment: are you able to edit the batch-files? if so, just remove the "pause" command at the end and they should just exit

Comment: If only it were that simple.  Alas, I am not allowed to edit the batch file.  Says so in the first sentence.

Comment: then you have to go with polling all the output and parsing it, see the two answers below

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like the following should work:

```
p = subprocess.Popen([path + '\\' + batchFile, path + '\\' + DIABFile],
                     bufsize=1, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
while p.poll() is None:
    line = p.stdout.readline()
    if line.startswith('Press any key to continue'):
        p.communicate('\r\n')
```

Comment: Thank you F.J.. I have tried using your process and the results are now added to my OP.

Comment: I was able to use this to grab the last line of output from the .bat file.  Unfortunately still wasn't able to get "press any key to continue" I believe due to the bug stated in the OP.  I am, however, accepting this answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could parse the output of the subprocess and match on the "Press any key to continue" phrase to continue on.

See this thread: [read subprocess stdout line by line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2804543/read-subprocess-stdout-line-by-line) especially what he posted as Update2

It might look like this:

```
import subprocess
proc = subprocess.Popen([path + '\\' + batchFile, path + '\\' + DIABFile],stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

for line in iter(proc.stdout.readline,''):
    if (line.rstrip() == "Press any key to..":
        break;
```

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the OP, none of the solutions were solving the problem. So at the end the solution from [Bryce](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34750079/11227118) solved the problem for me:

```py
subprocess.call([path + '\\' + batchFile, path + '\\' + DIABFile], stdin=subprocess.DEVNULL)
```

Comment: This worked for me too - simplest and elegant solution deserves more upvoting!

Answer (score -2):

The solution from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11729562/disable-pause-in-windows-bat-script) worked for me:

> Try to execute `cmd.exe /c YourCmdFile < nul`
>
> `YourCmdFile` - full path to your batch script

Comment: That answer doesn't explain how to do it in Python, but other answers there do.